# How would I be able to validate or format a location number 00-00-00-000-000 via Java-Script?

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting, geolocation

I have a question. How would I be able to validate or format a location number 00-00-00-000-000 digits 0-9 where 0 is via java-script.

something like this

```
function formatTime(time) {
    var result = false, m;
    var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)\s*$/;
    if ((m = time.match(re))) {
        result = (m[1].length == 2 ? "" : "0") + m[1] + ":" + m[2];
    }
    return result;
}
alert(formatTime(" 1:00"));
alert(formatTime("1:00 "));
alert(formatTime("1:00"));
alert(formatTime("2100"));
alert(formatTime("90:00")); // false
```

Comment: The regular expression is quite simple for that. I suggest you start with http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: So what is the input, a number that has that many digits?  or is a string in that format?  or is it a string in that format without leading zeros?  Then I am assuming the output is in the form `XX-XX-XX-XXX-XXX` where `X = 0-9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple function: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAAZ7/)

works for any input string that is in the format `X-X-X-X-X` where the first three Xs can be between 0 and 99 and the last 2 Xs can be between 0 and 999.

```
function doIt(lala) {
    var reg = /^\s*([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,3})\-([0-9]{1,3})\s*$/;
    var m = lala.match(reg);
    if(m) {
        var n1 = m[1].length == 1 ? ('0' + m[1]) : m[1];
        var n2 = m[2].length == 1 ? ('0' + m[2]) : m[2];
        var n3 = m[3].length == 1 ? ('0' + m[3]) : m[3];
        var n4 = m[4].length == 1 ? ('00' + m[4]) : (m[4].length == 2 ? '0' + m[4] : m[4]);
        var n5 = m[5].length == 1 ? ('00' + m[5]) : (m[5].length == 2 ? '0' + m[5] : m[5]);
        return (n1 + '-' + n2 + '-' + n3 + '-' + n4 + '-' + n5);
    }
    return ''; // you can choose to return false here
               // if you want to use this as some sort of validation
}
```